# how to check for dupes & not display them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check for duplicates in the list IDs in this function & not display them, All this is doing is adding the listIDs into the container but it is not checking for duplicates

```
     var listIDs = [];
      $.each(this.$el('lists', true), function(index, el) {
        listIDs.push($(el).data('containerid'));
    });
```

Any help would be greatful

Comment: If you could add the corresponding HTML, that _would be greatful_. Please see [ask] and **[mcve]**

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096019/php-array-push-how-not-to-push-if-the-array-already-contains-the-value ?

Comment: Just check if the containerid is already inside the listID array (indexOf) before you push it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether an item already exists in an array, you can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
var listIDs = [];
$.each(this.$el('lists', true), function(index, el) {
    var id = $(el).data('containerid')
    if (listIDs.indexOf(id) === -1) {
        listIDs.push(id)
    }
})
```

If `id` is not already in `listIDs`, then `listIDs.indexOf(id)` will return -1. In this case, we add it.

Answer (score 0):

You might try `unique()`. API [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/).

Then you could have `var uniqueIDs = ListIDs.unique()` and just use `uniqueIDs` for display purposes.

Hope that helps.